# hide show does not work after insertAfter jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm appending some rows to my table and when I click on one row different rows should open, I'm using slideToggle and hide show, but it doesn't work.. the click does work(I added console.log to check)- if I'm writing the rows inside the html it does work.
this is the function:

```
$('#table').on('click','.good_light_tags_reg',function(){
    console.log("hey");
    if ($('.good_light_sub_tag_reg').is(":visible")){
        $('.good_light_sub_tag_reg').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('.good_light_sub_tag_reg').show();
    }
});
```

the insert part..

```
    var identified_correctly = {};
var rows = "";

for (var i=1 ; i<(table.rows.length -1) ; i++){
    if (table.rows[i].className.includes('_tags_reg')){
        if (table.rows[i].className != table.rows[i+1].className) {
             val = table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML;
             var pos = val.indexOf("<br>");
             var res = parseFloat(val.substring(0, pos));
             identified_correctly[table.rows[i].className]=parseFloat(res);

        }
    }
    }
var items = Object.keys(identified_correctly).map(function(key) {
return [key, identified_correctly[key]];
});
items.sort(function(first, second) {
return first[1] - second[1];
});

for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    var class_name = items[i][0];

    var tags_rows = document.getElementsByClassName(class_name);

    var sub_tags_rows = document.getElementsByClassName(class_name.replace("_tags_","_sub_tag_"));
    for (var tag=0;tag<tags_rows.length;tag++){

        rows += tags_rows[tag].outerHTML;

        for (var sub_tag=0;sub_tag<sub_tags_rows;sub_tag++){
            rows += sub_tags_rows[sub_tag].outerHTML;

        }
    }
}
for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    $("#table").find("."+items[i][0]).remove();
        $("#table").find("."+items[i][0].replace("_tags_","_sub_tag_")).remove();
    }
    $(rows).insertAfter($(".tag_list_reg").last());
```

Comment: It would be nice if you show us the full code and show where exactly it doesn't work by providing a [mcve].

Comment: You may also just want to use the `.toggle` method, which hides an element if it is visible and shows it if it is hidden.

Comment: $(this) will not help because this is a click listenet for more than one row

Comment: @OriBA You have to use `$(this)`! Only then it will work.

Comment: check that every row is having the same class name which you are trying to hide and show. So if every row is having the same class name then every row will hide or show

Comment: the function works! the problem is with the append..after i use insetAfter the hide show tuggle does not work

Comment: can you post your html ? and how you are appending it to the dom

Comment: i cant use this because the hide show is not on the clicked class..

Answer (score 0):

try this using $(document)

```
$(document).on('click','.good_light_tags_reg',function(){
    $('.good_light_sub_tag_reg').toggle();
});
```

and if the element to show or hide is inside new row, try this

```
$(document).on('click','.good_light_tags_reg',function(){
    $(this).find('.good_light_sub_tag_reg').toggle();
});
```